# Live Preview when editing - not loading entries data

Tags: editor

Channel live preview set as:

```
site/index/{entry_id}
```

EE entries tag set as:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" limit="1" require_entry="yes" cache="yes" refresh="60" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
```

http://www.example.com/site/index/1234
This works without issue from the front end of the website.
From the live preview when editing an entry, the page does not display the entries tag contents.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which EE version you are using? And have you checked for any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a separate template for your live look. Remove `refresh="60"` and add `dynamic="no"` to it.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. Also you should not forget to set `status="closed"` to your template and to disable caching in the setting of your template. (works with EE 6.2.7)